# Korean file name changes to symbols after downloading

Tags: macos, file, encoding

file name in a webpage:
[image]

file name after downloading:

[image]

Comment: This is encoded using URL encoding. You will need to find an online service or a software than can decode it into Korean.

Comment: This is possibly a server-side misconfiguration. The simplest way to solve this is to copy the correct filename and replace the encoded filename by the correct one.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Expanding on Joy Jin's comment, you could copy the filename from the website, right-click the link, select "Download Linked File As..." and then paste the correct filename. For further troubleshooting, you may want to share the website you are downloading the file from.